# How to resolve autoload conflicts?

Tags: phpseclib

This is segment code my autoload,and then i running my php page.

It ouput msg 'File '/usr/share/nginx/html/m/crypt_hash.php' not found!'.

How to resolved it,thx so much:)

```
    function __autoload($className)
    {     
        $file = SERVER_ROOT . '/m/' .strtolower($className) .'.php';
        if(file_exists($file))
        {
           require_once($file);                   
        }
        else
        {
           die("File '$file' not found!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the file `'/usr/share/nginx/html/m/crypt_hash.php` exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$className = 'System_SSH_Agent';

$className = preg_replace('#^([^_]+)_#', '$1/', $className) . '.php';
```